# Static Assert if template parameter is of a certain template class

Tags: templates, c++11, partial-specialization

How can I throw a **static_assert** if template of `class A` is of a certain templated `class NOTALLOWED`?

```
template<typename T>
struct NOTALLOWED{

};

template<typename T>
struct A{
    // static_assert  if T == NOTALLOWED<...>  ??
}


// USING A< NOTALLOWED<int> >  is not allowed for example
```

the template class A should stay as it is given.
I want to prevent `A` taking a struct `NOTALLOWED` as template parameter

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You can write `is_instantiation` traits for specific templates:

```
template <typename T>
struct is_notallowed_instantiation { constexpr bool value = false; };

template <typename... Args>
struct is_notallowed_instantiation<NOTALLOWED<Args...>> { constexpr bool value = true; };
```

Then you can `static_assert` on that.

Answer (score 0):

Specialize on the special template:

```
template<typename T>
struct NOTALLOWED{

};

template<typename T>
struct A{
    // normal code
}

template<typename T>
struct A< NOTALLOWED<T> >{
    std::static_assert( sizeof(NOTALLOWED<T>) == -1, "This is not allowed!")
}
```